# Change color and linetype of one line in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset collected from a spectrometer; the number of spectra can be between 5 and a few hundred. I added a reference spectra to the dataset and plotted the whole lot. To distinguish between the spectra and the ref, I would like to be able to change the color and line type of the ref.

I already tried with `scale_linetype_manual` and `scale_color_manual` but did not succeed.

```
    Wavelength  EGG5    EGG6    EGG7    EGG8    EGG9    EGG10   Mean
337 516.87  3362    3400    3577    2727    3321    3627    3273.874
338 517.15  3389    3496    3567    2727    3368    3698    3285.288
339 517.44  3370    3479    3590    2728    3410    3711    3291.471
340 517.72  3363    3541    3584    2744    3403    3732    3308.022
341 518.01  3332    3528    3617    2780    3403    3722    3318.277
342 518.29  3350    3547    3610    2779    3413    3748    3321.633
343 518.58  3334    3489    3628    2759    3454    3772    3323.353
344 518.87  3371    3462    3630    2742    3499    3774    3341.572
345 519.15  3368    3494    3666    2761    3494    3747    3357.921
346 519.44  3407    3524    3639    2799    3470    3765    3364.273
347 519.72  3426    3536    3657    2791    3455    3792    3368.371
348 520.01  3449    3512    3640    2771    3462    3812    3380.655
349 520.29  3433    3494    3685    2761    3490    3791    3395.201
350 520.58  3478    3519    3673    2773    3475    3800    3406.921
351 520.86  3481    3518    3717    2798    3482    3802    3413.669
352 521.15  3497    3551    3694    2809    3468    3797    3417.065
353 521.43  3444    3551    3745    2832    3486    3785    3416.489
354 521.72  3447    3579    3710    2814    3516    3820    3422.496
355 522.00  3428    3575    3738    2787    3481    3843    3422.108
356 522.29  3475    3566    3725    2800    3518    3897    3429.982
357 522.57  3472    3577    3726    2832    3491    3894    3427.777
358 522.86  3512    3601    3714    2866    3552    3882    3444.234
359 523.14  3492    3630    3731    2846    3529    3835    3444.288
360 523.43  3515    3609    3744    2856    3567    3821    3455.061
361 523.71  3523    3621    3753    2816    3595    3845    3459.338
362 524.00  3522    3612    3720    2800    3555    3829    3457.784
363 524.28  3527    3641    3731    2791    3552    3861    3466.151
364 524.57  3511    3647    3742    2859    3530    3880    3469.151
365 524.85  3508    3656    3760    2876    3586    3917    3483.457
366 525.14  3526    3629    3745    2858    3609    3896    3475.342
367 525.42  3533    3598    3763    2845    3621    3907    3484.658
368 525.71  3600    3616    3774    2829    3623    3909    3485.237
369 525.99  3587    3633    3815    2861    3603    3933    3496.604
370 526.28  3598    3677    3795    2873    3593    3901    3495.921
371 526.56  3583    3676    3763    2914    3589    3910    3495.032
372 526.85  3586    3672    3719    2921    3588    3887    3491.266
373 527.13  3573    3653    3719    2929    3590    3875    3485.712
374 527.42  3537    3652    3734    2927    3582    3878    3489.273
375 527.70  3567    3681    3761    2938    3607    3880    3495.421
376 527.99  3587    3700    3751    2931    3632    3924    3506.284
377 528.27  3607    3705    3749    2928    3620    3890    3508.827
378 528.56  3588    3708    3736    2899    3631    3890    3504.655
379 528.84  3552    3685    3742    2882    3602    3867    3495.597
380 529.13  3554    3666    3716    2897    3614    3902    3499.396
381 529.41  3513    3618    3742    2877    3571    3934    3498.964
382 529.70  3561    3619    3753    2884    3598    3949    3504.813
383 529.98  3582    3622    3816    2844    3618    3919    3506.935
384 530.26  3625    3667    3805    2868    3613    3897    3510.910
385 530.55  3603    3659    3839    2894    3618    3917    3507.428
386 530.83  3593    3691    3830    2920    3607    3954    3501.018
387 531.12  3613    3672    3833    2909    3631    3966    3503.317
388 531.40  3631    3675    3815    2878    3581    3925    3500.795
389 531.69  3627    3615    3771    2890    3569    3909    3503.964
390 531.97  3614    3633    3765    2865    3590    3893    3501.849
391 532.26  3596    3650    3775    2868    3664    3923    3512.464
392 532.54  3615    3700    3797    2852    3673    3943    3519.813
393 532.82  3584    3704    3781    2873    3591    3952    3517.381
394 533.11  3593    3723    3781    2878    3543    3931    3511.986
395 533.39  3631    3742    3776    2885    3561    3929    3516.270
396 533.68  3642    3739    3823    2900    3608    3935    3523.061
397 533.96  3663    3696    3810    2893    3639    3974    3534.691
398 534.25  3590    3678    3814    2886    3649    3968    3533.288
399 534.53  3584    3677    3821    2866    3657    3988    3535.514
400 534.81  3587    3711    3795    2872    3624    3964    3531.615
401 535.10  3575    3681    3827    2904    3639    3993    3539.518
402 535.38  3554    3683    3763    2928    3634    3959    3549.532
403 535.67  3531    3673    3778    2957    3646    3951    3553.817
404 535.95  3577    3687    3761    2921    3660    3936    3543.496
405 536.24  3630    3662    3828    2940    3679    3966    3550.511
406 536.52  3664    3670    3854    2875    3689    3983    3557.536
407 536.80  3664    3709    3858    2874    3655    3998    3577.245
408 537.09  3644    3778    3835    2893    3680    4017    3580.881
409 537.37  3656    3796    3837    2949    3695    4044    3593.831
410 537.66  3659    3799    3860    2979    3708    4052    3589.629
411 537.94  3679    3786    3892    2956    3693    4042    3587.568
412 538.22  3635    3778    3906    2915    3670    4027    3588.734
413 538.51  3671    3793    3909    2925    3686    4062    3608.561
414 538.79  3700    3791    3861    2920    3687    4121    3621.248
415 539.08  3731    3848    3862    2997    3722    4120    3637.788
416 539.36  3723    3849    3875    3033    3742    4106    3647.777
417 539.64  3739    3868    3942    3075    3769    4072    3657.374
418 539.93  3735    3861    3952    3044    3767    4116    3663.442
419 540.21  3776    3890    4021    3057    3765    4101    3675.629
420 540.50  3765    3910    4030    3033    3785    4102    3691.608
421 540.78  3831    3931    4078    3054    3836    4103    3709.950
422 541.06  3827    3953    4098    3016    3843    4130    3725.504
423 541.35  3871    3969    4112    3025    3872    4163    3744.403
424 541.63  3878    3966    4132    3055    3856    4181    3756.741
425 541.91  3864    3966    4089    3076    3920    4213    3766.216
426 542.20  3842    3999    4107    3098    3935    4246    3780.737
427 542.48  3866    4038    4107    3066    3950    4254    3788.410
428 542.76  3930    4043    4120    3085    3958    4285    3812.446
429 543.05  3970    4069    4137    3096    3935    4272    3838.629
430 543.33  3968    4103    4153    3130    3948    4341    3870.597
431 543.62  3971    4145    4196    3174    3966    4334    3883.356
432 543.90  3980    4171    4238    3192    4048    4384    3901.036
433 544.18  4016    4156    4282    3206    4105    4393    3918.155
434 544.47  4054    4195    4315    3200    4124    4458    3945.201
435 544.75  4123    4221    4347    3241    4131    4490    3976.065
436 545.03  4176    4279    4362    3229    4129    4490    3999.345
437 545.32  4196    4294    4368    3247    4121    4476    4019.050
438 545.60  4197    4336    4376    3242    4138    4525    4036.065
439 545.88  4205    4379    4394    3294    4190    4553    4080.453
440 546.17  4250    4383    4471    3291    4259    4621    4112.651
441 546.45  4324    4413    4489    3328    4306    4622    4146.709
442 546.73  4355    4437    4542    3381    4369    4690    4163.784
443 547.02  4385    4542    4562    3447    4397    4711    4202.871
444 547.30  4441    4560    4605    3453    4484    4790    4231.701
445 547.58  4493    4630    4594    3435    4496    4788    4264.464
446 547.87  4515    4671    4592    3412    4532    4827    4284.018
447 548.15  4518    4726    4666    3461    4496    4808    4310.137
448 548.43  4590    4765    4762    3520    4554    4856    4343.259
449 548.72  4610    4805    4823    3571    4604    4889    4375.237
450 549.00  4653    4848    4850    3564    4670    4916    4403.590
451 549.28  4626    4839    4848    3553    4663    4962    4432.097
452 549.57  4713    4836    4867    3639    4691    5003    4470.795
453 549.85  4768    4859    4896    3689    4714    5068    4510.371
454 550.13  4828    4895    4951    3728    4716    5126    4545.076
455 550.41  4810    4993    4972    3643    4730    5148    4572.414
456 550.70  4836    5075    5021    3698    4762    5176    4607.784
457 550.98  4883    5174    5043    3698    4844    5188    4641.068
458 551.26  4944    5204    5156    3806    4877    5272    4686.183
459 551.55  4994    5241    5183    3795    4912    5349    4717.932
460 551.83  5029    5247    5224    3889    4961    5370    4750.104
461 552.11  5112    5277    5189    3868    5019    5379    4782.029
462 552.40  5134    5343    5196    3906    5050    5415    4823.004
463 552.68  5185    5426    5247    3912    5103    5462    4863.273
464 552.96  5212    5459    5318    3986    5142    5488    4900.011
465 553.24  5284    5462    5384    4000    5240    5544    4945.446
466 553.53  5339    5466    5449    3985    5262    5594    4976.561
467 553.81  5391    5554    5513    3986    5318    5612    5019.626
468 554.09  5415    5640    5570    4006    5319    5612    5045.396
469 554.38  5448    5721    5614    4064    5380    5674    5098.770
470 554.66  5544    5765    5653    4051    5437    5751    5138.752
471 554.94  5585    5793    5634    4089    5494    5821    5176.392
472 555.22  5624    5808    5667    4112    5563    5827    5202.475
473 555.51  5622    5837    5693    4185    5622    5892    5236.281
474 555.79  5648    5845    5760    4214    5672    5918    5265.612
475 556.07  5709    5953    5783    4286    5668    5985    5316.511
476 556.35  5757    6016    5849    4313    5704    5955    5359.302
477 556.64  5797    6109    5927    4322    5776    5991    5412.820
478 556.92  5848    6135    5989    4292    5832    6037    5443.241
479 557.20  5856    6199    6049    4292    5852    6167    5479.432
480 557.48  5949    6274    6125    4354    5838    6226    5515.306
481 557.77  5991    6303    6165    4419    5896    6261    5553.723
482 558.05  6085    6362    6209    4445    5955    6272    5592.842
483 558.33  6091    6392    6258    4475    5999    6315    5629.468
484 558.61  6158    6483    6267    4465    6062    6388    5669.486
485 558.90  6205    6511    6315    4541    6146    6430    5713.281
486 559.18  6244    6546    6314    4565    6237    6515    5755.496
487 559.46  6304    6549    6393    4619    6261    6565    5793.651
488 559.74  6357    6602    6351    4598    6276    6610    5810.910
489 560.03  6423    6661    6353    4623    6281    6660    5840.727
490 560.31  6467    6769    6401    4636    6325    6656    5883.446
491 560.59  6446    6782    6536    4720    6361    6675    5938.773
492 560.87  6508    6876    6651    4722    6408    6648    5980.385
493 561.16  6552    6881    6669    4736    6441    6703    6014.791
494 561.44  6672    6943    6663    4734    6442    6769    6043.910
495 561.72  6757    6985    6649    4743    6507    6820    6085.784
496 562.00  6801    7076    6689    4786    6544    6868    6136.007
497 562.28  6838    7177    6721    4837    6661    6932    6185.385
498 562.57  6862    7240    6782    4935    6727    7017    6229.784
499 562.85  6922    7301    6894    5022    6785    7087    6265.989
500 563.13  7003    7353    6959    5079    6823    7082    6320.410
501 563.41  7064    7414    7001    5081    6841    7169    6374.471
502 563.69  7120    7451    7003    5072    6921    7197    6425.284
503 563.98  7157    7513    7069    5065    6989    7331    6466.151
504 564.26  7241    7588    7096    5074    7043    7369    6511.083
505 564.54  7294    7653    7181    5089    7088    7459    6567.119
506 564.82  7353    7735    7219    5127    7095    7479    6609.558
507 565.10  7430    7764    7311    5179    7175    7515    6649.820
508 565.39  7493    7842    7364    5259    7265    7579    6711.403
509 565.67  7606    7949    7443    5277    7345    7672    6786.032
510 565.95  7662    8057    7549    5332    7442    7773    6872.349
511 566.23  7732    8162    7618    5332    7519    7855    6916.7  

AEDDataMelt <- data.frame( melt(AEDPlotData, id.vars = 'Wavelength', variable = 'series'))
Q <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = subset(AEDDataMelt, series!="Mean"),aes(x=Wavelength, y=value, col=series))+
  scale_color_manual(values = brewer.pal(n=(ncol(AEDPlotData)-1),name = "Dark2" ))+
  geom_line(data = subset(AEDDataMelt, series=="Mean"),aes(x = Wavelength, y=value,col= series, linetype = series))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = "dash")+


ggplotly(Q)
```

At this point I get a dashed line but did not succeed in changing the color of the mean reference line. Also the legend changed in format ffrom EGG5 to (EGG5,1).

Comment: Please share a minimal part of your dataset in a copy paste friendly format. You may use `dplut(head(<your dataset>))`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the ggplotly bit, but manually setting a specific colour and linetype for only one of your lines is quite straightforward. Your code seems to be  somewhat overcomplicated for your task and you could simply achieve what you stated by manually adding those scales:

```
ggplot(AEDDataMelt) +
  geom_line(aes(Wavelength, value, colour = series, linetype = series)) +
  # First six lines are of one type, last line should be different
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2)) +
  # First six lines are from the brewer pallette, last one a custom colour
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(brewer.pal(6, "Dark2"), "black"))
```

Which gave me this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution, this will work fine on this small dataset, but as I wrote in the introduction the amount of data in the set varies. I fear this solution will take a lot of effort when the dataset grows to more than 400 entries. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Hello Teunbrand, I have used your solution as inspiration an came up with a fitting solution for a varying amount of data.

Comment: I apologise I must have overlooked that piece of info. Glad you were able to generalise it yourself though!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of teunbrand,
I came to the following solution:

```
AEDDataMelt <- data.frame( melt(AEDPlotData, id.vars = 'Wavelength', variable = 
'series'))
MyLineType <- rep.int(1,(length(AEDPlotData[1, 1:(ncol(AEDPlotData)-2)])))
MyLineType <- append(MyLineType,2,after = length(MyLineType))

Q <- ggplot(AEDDataMelt) +
      geom_line(aes(Wavelength, value, colour = series, linetype = series)) +
      # First n lines are of one type, last line is reference and should be different
      scale_linetype_manual(values = MyLineType)+
      # First six lines are from the brewer pallette, last one a custom colour
      scale_colour_manual(values = c(brewer.pal((length(MyLineType)-1), "Dark2"), 
"black"))
ggplotly(Q)
```